# Not able to create custom numeric keypad

Tags: android, android-activity, keyword

I want to create a numeric keypad, but when I click on any of the textview, it does not display any number in EditText. I think TextView's `OnClickListener` event is not working. How can I solve this probliem?

This is my code.

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText edtpassword;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv9;
    TextView tv10;
    ImageView iv11;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_keypad);
        edtpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_2);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_3);
        tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_4);
        tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_5);
        tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_6);
        tv7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_7);
        tv8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_8);
        tv9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_9);
        tv10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_clear);
        iv11=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_backspace);
        setViews();

    }
    private void setViews(){
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(1);
            }
        });
       tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(2);
            }
        });
       tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(3);
            }
        });
       tv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(4);
            }
        });
       tv5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(5);
            }
        });
       tv6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(6);
            }
        });
       tv7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(7);
            }
        });
       tv8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(8);
            }
        });
       tv9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(9);
            }
        });
       tv10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onT9KeyClicked(10);
            }
        });
        // find view references...
        // set OnClickListener to each key view...
    }

    private void onT9KeyClicked(int key) {
        switch (key) {
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_0:
            edtpassword.setText(1);
//          edtpassword.append("0");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_1:
            edtpassword.append("1");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_2:
            edtpassword.append("2");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_3:
            edtpassword.append("3");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_4:
            edtpassword.append("4");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_5:
            edtpassword.append("5");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_6:
            edtpassword.append("6");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_7:
            edtpassword.append("7");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_8:
            edtpassword.append("8");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_9:
            edtpassword.append("9");
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_backspace: {
            // delete one character
            String passwordStr = edtpassword.getText().toString();
            if (passwordStr.length() > 0) {
                String newPasswordStr = new StringBuilder(passwordStr)
                        .deleteCharAt(passwordStr.length() - 1).toString();
                edtpassword.setText(newPasswordStr);
            }
        }
            break;
        case R.id.anti_theft_t9_key_clear:
            // clear password field
            edtpassword.setText(null);
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

This is my layout file.

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#287AA9"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your Password"
        android:textColor="#287AA9"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edtpassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock2"
        android:inputType="number"
        />



<include
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    layout="@layout/activity_main" 
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my second layout file which I included in `new_keypad` layout.
new_keypad.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:background="@color/white_gray"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end" >



    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_1"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_one"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_2"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_two"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_3"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_three"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_4"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_four"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_5"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_five"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_6"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_six"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_7"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_seven"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_8"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_eight"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_9"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_nine"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_clear"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/anti_theft_keyboard_clear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_0"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_zero"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/anti_theft_t9_key_backspace"
            style="@style/anti_theft_t9_key"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this line from the EditText definition in XML:

```
    android:inputType="number"
```

Also, why do you make it an EditText if you want to provide input from custom keypad instead of the system one? You should make it a TextView :-)

Comment: changed the code according but still when i press on any number it doesn't display on textview of password. :(